# Poor Performance when logging into SQL Server using Active Directory in Win Forms C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, performance, active-directory

My application connects to a SQL Server using windows authentication. I have a login in on the server which is a Active Directory group. If the user is in the Active Directory group then it logs you into the SQL server and gives you the correct permissions.

However this way is much slower than using SQL Server authentication, is there any way to increase the performance.

I did some tests for how long it takes to login into the server:

- SQL Server Authentication - 0.068414 s
- Windows Authentication using AD - 0.182627 s

Thanks

Comment: You are a very lucky man if your program has only this problem

Comment: @Steve what other problems should I have then ?

Comment: I don't see why 0.182627 s is a problem?

Comment: @butterbox those results are how long it takes to open the connection, not actually running any queries. The application has too run a lot of store procedures. For exmaple it takes 1.7 seconds to open up a page using AD, but 0.2 when not using it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't be worried about this. All MS technologies for connecting to database have a database connection pool will be kept in the background so there won't be many opening and closing of connections.

0.18267s is most likely nothing compared to actual queries you run on the server.

If you really want to look into this some more you can try following:

- make sure AD is not too busy
- make sure there is good connectivity between SQL Server and AD (use Ping to verify)
- if possible give permissions to AD users vs AD group.

Answer (score 0):

I was just going to add a comment, but it got long. Now its here.

Anyhew. When you provide credentials to SQL Server directly it can perform its own authentication and return.

However, when you specify AD credentials SQL Server then has to do another round trip to the Domain Controller to confirm your credentials (although technically I think you are actually passing a token. Anyway).

My 2c.